# Element uses-permission#android.permission.CAMERA duplicated with element declared at AndroidManifest.xml

Tags: android, angular, ionic3, android-manifest

The question title is the error I receive while deploying my Ionic app for Android. I think (but am not sure) this emanates because I use both the `barcodeScanner` and `Camera` plugins in my app, which both require the Camera permission. Is there something I should be doing when using two plugins which require the same permission? Also, is it adviseable to edit the `AndroidManifest` file, and if yes, how exactly should I do it?

**Edit:**

Actually, the problem wasn't because I used the `barcodeScanner` and `Camera` plugins in my app. It was caused by the existence of `barcodeScanner` and `qrScanner` among my plugins (even though I used just `barcodeScanner` in my app. Even though the accepted answer eliminated the error, I find it worthwhile pointing out that removing one of these plugins did as well:

```
cordova plugin remove cordova-plugin-qrscanner
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

As it is very clear from the Error message that two elements i.e. plugins are using same permission. To resolve such issue you can do the following:

- Comment out/remove the line of `uses-permission` and `uses-feature` in ...\plugins\phonegap-plugin-barcodescanner\plugin.xml

  ```
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA"/>
  <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera">
  ```
- `rm platform android`
- `add platform android`
- `ionic cordova run android`

No need to touch `AndroidManifest.xml` file and also it is not advisable.

Hope this will help.

Comment: It did help!! I also had to comment out `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA"/>`

Comment: @che-azeh  happy to help you.